# Linear combination and rotational matrix rotates in the opposite direction

Tags: matrices, rotations

I have an aviation-like coordinate system where the green, blue, and red arrows represents the unit vectors on the x-, y-, and z-axis and oriented in a way that obeys the right-hand-rule.

If I yaw a vector (e.g. the blue, y-unit vector) by 20° (i.e. to rotate the y-unit vector CW by 20°, I can either rewrite the new, rotated vector in terms of the original frame (the linear combination way):

$$ \mathbf{v}=-\sin(20°)\,\hat{x} + \cos(20°)\,\hat{y} = -0.34\,\hat{x} + 0.94\,\hat{y}$$

or, I can apply a full rotational matrix on the y-unit-vector instead:

$$ 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{v}_x &= \cos(20°)\,\hat{x} + \sin(20°)\,\hat{y} \\ 
\mathbf{v}_y &= -\sin(20°)\,\hat{x} + \cos(20°)\,\hat{y} \\ 
\mathbf{v}_z &= \hat{z}
\end{align}
\;\;\;\implies\;\;\;
\mathbf{v} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(20°) & \sin(20°) & 0 \\ 
-\sin(20°) & \cos(20°) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\hat{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.34 \\
0.94 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Either calculation should provide me with the same result - but I get one resulting vector rotated CCW opposite to the direction of rotation under the right-hand convention.  I couldn't find any error individually in the linear combination or in the rotational matrix, nor can I find any discrepancy between the two ... after all, the linear combination is just a piece of the system of equations (precisely the 2nd equation) that forms the 3x3 rotational matrix.

Could someone explain why their angle of rotation are different, and when should I use which to know I will get the correct direction of rotation?

[image]

Comment: The way that you have chosen the rotation matrix, automatically assumes that the angle you choose is CCW rotation (standard assumption in mathematics). In a way, you have to boil down the rotation into a single number, whose sign tells if it's CW or CCW. Perhaps in aviation you're used to positive value being CW? In mathematics it's CCW. Solution? Just flip the sign of the angle in the matrix calculation (if you want to stay in the "aviation world") and you will ge the desired result.

Comment: @MattiP. both in the formulation of the linear equation and in the rotation matrix, I apply the same right-hand rule where the thumb points toward the positive direction of the axis.  There is no difference or any flipping whatsoever between the "aviation" frame and the coordinates used in maths.  If the Z points out (like we use to seeing), it's CCW.  If the Z points into the page (as shown in my image), it's CW.  The Z-axis isn't flipped, the "aviation" frame just rotate the "math" frame by 180deg around x-axis just so z points to center of the earth.